# Attaching a phram mtd0 device to gadget serial mass storage

Tags: linux, usb, kernel-modules, ram, ramdisk

I'm using a Atmel SAMA5D3, I have created two phram devices /dev/mtd0 and /dev/mtd1 I am trying to attach them to a gadget mass storage module.

```
    insmod g_acm_ms.ko file=/dev/mtd0,/dev/mtd1
```

The error I get is

```
   g_acm_ms 500000.gadget: failed to start g_acm_ms: -22
   insmod: can't insert 'g_acm_ms.ko': Invalid argument
```

and from dmesg|tail

```
   atmel_usba_udc 500000.gadget: MMIO registers at 0xf8030000 mapped at c48d0000
   atmel_usba_udc 500000.gadget: FIFO at 0x00500000 mapped at c4e00000
   lun0: invalid file type: /dev/mtd0
   g_acm_ms 500000.gadget: failed to start g_acm_ms: -22
   lun0: invalid file type: /dev/mtd0
   g_acm_ms 500000.gadget: failed to start g_acm_ms: -22
```

If I create a backing file

```
   dd if=/dev/zero of=backing.file bs=1M count=4
   insmod g_acm_ms.ko file=backing.file
```

It work fine

How do I attach the mtd devices instead?

Answer (score 0):

I figured the problem out, I had forgotten to

```
     insmod mtd_blkdevs.ko
     insmod mtdblock.ko
```

then use the resulting /dev/mtdblock0 as the backing file